# Django-Compressor cannot find files when it's actually there

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-compressor

I just installed django-compressor to my project and I am getting below error message.

> TemplateSyntaxError at / Caught UncompressableFileError while
>   rendering: 'js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js' could not be found in the
>   COMPRESS_ROOT '/Users/taelimoh/Dropbox/gluwa-git/static' or with
>   staticfiles.

This also happens when I try to compress css files.

Of course, the files are there and it works fine when I don't try to compress them with django-compressor.

below is my template

```
...
    {% compress js %}
        <!--Javascripts-->
        <!--Libraries-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    {% endcompress %}
...
```

and this is my settings.py

```
COMPRESS_ENABLED = True

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    ##############################################
    'appconf',# required by django-compressor
    'versiontools',# required by django-compressor
    'compressor',#https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor
    ...
)
```

I am using google app engine and my django version is 1.3.
The issue was produced on my development server.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bit late, but the documentation states that any files that are configured with a static handler in your `app.yaml` aren't readable by the application. Thankfully, there's also a switch to enable your application to read these files. You can read about it [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig?csw=1#application_readable_1). In essence, you'd want to do this

```
handlers:
- url: /static
- static_dir: staticfiles
- application_readable: true
```

in your `app.yaml` (note the `application_readable`). I struggled with this for a while because `os.path.exists` was always failing. Hope this helps.

Comment: This sounds promising. I'll check it out and accept this. I ended up using not using compressor so it will take some time. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries! Hope it works for you. I was trying to use django-compressor's offline cache and ran into the issue you described so I guess you were trying to do something similar?

Comment: Yes, I think I was attempting the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

GAE apps have no write permissions to files. If Django-compressor is trying to write the compressed files to the filesystem, that'll fail.

Comment: oops, you're right, I meant django-compressor.  I dunno why other moderators rejected the edit.